# How to use Mailkit with OAuth2 in an ASP.NET MVC application on Azure AD?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, mailkit

My situation is an ASP.NET MVC application that need to send emails. My email is Office 365

I tried these steps https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md

On Azure AD as permission, I have Microsoft Graph and Microsoft Exchange Online.

How configure the permissions on AD for that work with mailkit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Configure the below **API permissions** on Azure AD to authenticate mailkit:

*Go to Azure AD application -> Add a permission -> APIs my organization uses -> Office 365 Exchange Online*

[image]

Assign application and delegated API permissions based on your application:

[image]

And add grant access to the user:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "xxx@example.com" -User ServicePrincipalID -AccessRights FullAccess
```

Make use of below code to authenticate:

```cs
var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create (clientId)
    .WithAuthority ($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0")
    .WithCertificate (certificate) // or .WithClientSecret (clientSecret)
    .Build ();
 
var scopes = new string[] {
    // For IMAP and POP3, use the following scope
    "https://ps.outlook.com/.default"

    // For SMTP, use the following scope
    // "https://outlook.office365.com/.default"
};

var authToken = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient (scopes).ExecuteAsync ();
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2 (accountEmailAddress, authToken.AccessToken);

using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    await client.ConnectAsync ("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync (oauth2);
    await client.DisconnectAsync (true);
}
```

**Reference:**

[MailKit/ExchangeOAuth2.md at master · jstedfast/MailKit · GitHub](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/ExchangeOAuth2.md)